# Getting: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" error when trying to register an account

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get login system code working in vuejs, however when I try to register, it always gives this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys (<anonymous>) at VueComponent.setErrors (vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:1892) at eval (Register.vue?0103:282)`

In vee-validate.esm.js, here's the part that shows the error:

```
        setErrors: function (errors) {
        var _this = this;
        Object.keys(errors).forEach(function (key) {
            var provider = _this.refs[key];
            if (!provider)
                return;
            var errorArr = errors[key] || [];
            errorArr = typeof errorArr === 'string' ? [errorArr] : errorArr;
            provider.setErrors(errorArr);
        });
        this.observers.forEach(function (observer) {
            observer.setErrors(errors);
        });
    }
```

And here's the part in register.view that shows the error:

```
            .catch((error) => {
          this.$toast({
            component: ToastificationContent,
            position: "top-right",
            props: {
              title: "Register failed!",
              icon: "CoffeeIcon",
              variant: "danger",
            },
          });

          error.hasOwnProperty("response")
            ? this.$refs.registerForm.setErrors(error.response.data.error)
            : this.$refs.registerForm.setErrors(error.error);
        }
```

I've tried adding `if (errors != null)` before the Object.keys(errors) part, but that only gets rid of the error message, however the code still doesn't run. I'm pretty new to vuejs so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe one of your best courses would be to make sure you only get into `setErrors` when it is useful, that is when `errors` is not null.

Comment: This means that data that is provided to setErrors is not an object. It's unknown why you expect it to be objects.

Comment: @EstusFlask so that probably means that something somewhere else is causing `errors` to be null?

Comment: Unless there are other setErrors that you didn't show, this certainly means that error.response.data.error or error.error aren't objects.